# How Can I Solve cv2.drawContours() Error?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to do find contours in camera video and Draw the line with Contours

But I got Something Error on my code :|

```
File ".\Contour.py", line 28, in <module>
    cv2.drawContours(frame, contours[i], 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)     
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-r2ue8w6k\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2490: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= contourIdx && contourIdx < (int)last in function 'cv::drawContours'
```

What I should do in this situation?

My Full Code

```
import cv2
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # if cap.isOpened() == False:
    #     print("Cant Open The Camera")
    #     sys.exit(1)

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # if ret == False:
    #     print("Can't load the Camera")
    #     sys.exit(1)
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    print(len(contours))
    
    if len(contours) > 0:
        # cnt = contours[len(contours) - 1]
        for i in range(len(contours)):
            cv2.drawContours(frame, contours[i], 1, (0, 0, 255), 3)     


    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    # cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
    # cv2.imshow("binary", binary)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My Environment

**openCV : '4.5.1'**

**python : '3.7.0'**

**Camera : Laptop Built-In Camera**

**:D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.drawContours` is expecting a list and the index in that list you want to plot. In your code, the list has just one item, so 1 is out of range.
You could fix that using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(contours):
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [contours[i]], 0, (0,0,255), 3)
```

If you want to draw all contours, simply pass all the contours to the function:

```
cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
```

As a side note, since `cv2.drawContours` overwrites the input image (`frame` in your code), I would recommend creating a copy before drawing the contours, so you can keep the original image for further processing if needed:

```
output = frame.copy()
cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
```